# Gatsby set lang attribute to html

Tags: html, gatsby, lang

How would you do it? modify the public folder doesn't seem to work...  make your own build and host it how it is? maybe there is a function that I still don't know. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 36):

**Gatsby v5**

Gatsby now has its own Head API: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-head/

Export a head component from your page file, including the html element:

```
export function Head() {
  return (
    <>
      <html lang="en" />
    </>
  )
}
```

**Outdated:**

Gatsby recommends using [react helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) for this. You can find a lot of best practices around this topic if you look at the [Gatsby documentation - how to add meta data](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/add-page-metadata/).

Follow the step by step guide in the documentation. React helmet is really powerful. Coming back to your question, that's how you can alter the HTML language attribute:

```
<Helmet
  htmlAttributes={{
    lang: 'en',
  }}
/>
```

Comment: This is not the way to do it in 2022. Gatsby recommend using Gatsby Head which is built-in: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-head/

Answer (score 8):

According to [the new Head Api doc](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-head/) (added in `gatsby@4.19.0`) you can avoid the `Helmet` dependency including inside the `gatsby-ssr.js` or `gatsby-ssr.ts` file, using the `setHtmlAttributes` function.

```js
exports.onRenderBody = ({ setHtmlAttributes }) => {
  setHtmlAttributes({ lang: "en" })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Arthur Violy's answer using the Gatsby Head API and **ES6**:

```
export const onRenderBody = ({ setHtmlAttributes }) => {
  setHtmlAttributes({ lang: "en" });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Just an add-in to [@Andre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64503718/5668956), in case you want to use the [Open Graph protocol property](https://ogp.me/), e.g: `xmlns:og`, `xmlns:fb`...
Just wrap the key with the single quote `'`

```html
<Helmet htmlAttributes={
    {
    lang: 'en',
    'xmlns:og': 'http://ogp.me/ns#',
    'xmlns:fb': 'http://ogp.me/ns/fb#'
    }
  }>

    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
    ....
</Helmet>
```

Answer (score -1):

if using gatsby v5

Just place

`return ( <> <html lang="en" /> </>)`

Into Header function